# Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{2018}{100+e^{x}}$ defined $\forall x\in\Bbb R$. How many integers are there in the range of $f$?

Tags: functions, contest-math

The aforementioned question appeared in an undergraduate entrance test and hence assumes high-school level knowledge of calculus. My motivation to solve this question is this:

1. For $f(x)$ to assume integral values, $100+e^x\le2018$ for sure.
2. Further, $e^x>0$  $\forall x\in\Bbb R$.
3. Now, $2018=2*1009$. For $e^x=909$ and $e^x=1918$(both values can be rightfully assumed, given the continuity and increasing nature of $e^x$ over $\Bbb R$), $f(x)$ equals 2 and 1, respectively. Thus, I figured that there are only two integers in the range of $f$.

My conclusion is at odds with the actual answer(there are *20 such integral values*), as depicted by the graph of $f(x)$ below:
[image: graph]

I would like answers to the following:

> 1.Which step(s) in my solution was/were flawed, and why?
>
> 2.Provide an analytical(non-graphical) solution to this problem(since the actual test does not permit graphing calculators).

Comment: Other relevant tags may be added; I'm not sure if this question concerns either analysis or number theory.

Comment: Uh.... Just because the graph is divided into eight sections doesn't mean the graph is divided into *integers*.  Why do you think the graph shows $8$ integers?  (Between 20 and 0 are *more* than 8 integers)

Comment: @fleablood My bad. I'll fix that in the question.

Comment: Forget that $e^x$ is a function and just pretend it takes integer values in the range you've already found. How many numbers of the form $100 + n$ divide $2018$ evenly?

Comment: Your step 3) is completely incomprehensible to me.

Comment: What if $e^x = 572\frac 23$?  Then $100 + e^x = 672\frac 23$ then $\frac {2018}{100+e^x}= \frac {2018}{672\frac 23} = \frac {3*2018}{3*672 + 2} = \frac {6054}{2018} = 3$.  .... I think your error was in assuming $e^x$ has to be an integer.  It doesn't.

Comment: @fleablood I think my reasoning was too naive; I could only figure out that 2018 would be completely divisible by $100+e^x$ when the latter was equal to 1009 or 2018 itself.

Comment: @fleablood Right on point. I assumed $e^x$ to be an integer.

Comment: Okay, as soon as a posted the comment I saw what you meant.  $100 + e^x$ doesn't have to be an integer.   You can get $\frac {2018}{100+e^x} = k$ if $2018 = k(100 + e^x)$ if $e^x = \frac {2018-100k}k$.  For instance $\frac {2018}{100+e^x} =13$ if $2018=13(100+e^x)$ if $2018=1300 + 13e^x$ of $e^x=\frac {718}{13}$.  That's possible by the continuity of $e^x$.

Comment: @fleablood Adding this remark to your answer will make it more valuable.

Comment: I don't know about that.... The point is you don't have to solve for $x$.  It's enough to know it is continuous so it hits all integers in it's range.  And as the range is $(0,20,18)$ it hits all the integers..... Oh, all right.. I'll add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's continuous.

$0 < e^x < \infty$

$100 < 100 + e^x < \infty$

$0 < \frac 1{100+e^x} < \frac 1{100}$ and

$0 < \frac {2018}{100+e^x} < \frac {2018}{100} < 20.18$.

So there are at most the integers $1,...., 20$.  Or $20$.

And as $x\to \infty$ we get $\frac {2018}{100+e^x} \to 0$ it does get lower than $1$.

And as $x\to -\infty$ we get $\frac {2018}{100+e^x}\to 20.18$ it does get higher than $20.18$.

And as its continuous it hits every integer between $1$ and $20$.  So $20$ integer values.

======

If that's not enough:

If you want to solve $\frac {2018}{100 + e^x} =k$ for an integer $k$ then we can do

$2018 = (100+e^x)k=100k + e^x*k$

$2018 - 100k = e^x*k$

$e^x = \frac {2018-100k}k$

$x =\ln \frac {2018-100k}k$.

The requirements for this are that $k \ne 0$.  ANd that $\frac {2018-100k}k > 0$.

If $k > 0$ the we need $\frac {2018-100k}k>0 \iff 2018-100k > 0\iff k< 20.18\iff k \le 20$.

If $k < 0$ then we need $\frac {2018-100k}k > 0\iff 2018-100k < 0\iff k>20.18$ but $k < 0$ *while* $k > 20.18$ is impossible.

So $f(x) =k$ is possible for all $k=1,2,.....,20$.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually solved is:

> How many $x$ are there so that $100+e^x$ and $\frac{2018}{100+e^x}$ are both integers?

where the former restriction is not part of the question. It's better to reason that when $100+e^x$ is among the values $\frac{2018}{1},\,\frac{2018}{2},\,\frac{2018}3,\ldots,\frac{2018}{2018}$, this expression comes out to be an integer. You will see that $20$ of these are in the possible range of values of $100+e^x$ which is $(100,\infty)$. Your proof can be corrected by plugging this little fix into it.

Comment: Indeed I overlooked this possibility. Since $e^x>0 \forall x\in\Bbb R$, I assumed any possibility for $f$ to be an integer would be restricted to $100+e^x$ being an integer.